# Как вставить этот код перед body с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код партнерки, как  его можно вставить в тело `html`, перед `body`? с помощью js
вот код :

```
 <!--noindex-->
    <script type="text/javascript" class="ambn" src="//x.mobalert.net/ma.php?s=79849&tr=50&to=1&   acl=60&cncl=1&scr=0&tok=1&tcl=24&html=1&n=0"></script>
<!--/noindex-->
```

я пробовал:

```
function() {
    var script=document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript.js";
    script.src="";
    script.text=alert('куку');
    document.body.appebdChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.body.appebdChild(script);
```

синтаксическая ошибка (`appendChild`).

Вставить в самом начале body -

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.body.firstChild, script);
```

Answer (score 1):

вот по моему рабочий вариант.во всяком случае у меня:

```
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.type="text/javascript";
script.src="//x.mobalert.net/ma.php?s=79849&tr=50&to=1& acl=60&cncl=1&scr=0&tok=1&tcl=24&html=1&n=0";
script.classList.add("ambn");
document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild);
```