# Как вставить код в тело страницы при помощи js?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код  Партнерки:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="ambn" src="//x.mobalert.net/ma.php?s=79849&tr=50&to=1&acl=60&cncl=1&scr=0&tok=1&tcl=24&html=1&n=0">
```

Как мне его вставить перед `</body>` используя javascript ?
Пробовал следующую реализацию :

```
function() {      
var script=document.createElement("script"); 
script.type="text/javascript.js"; 
script.src="//x.mobalert.net/ma.php?s=79849&tr=50&to=1& acl=60&cncl=1&scr=0&tok=1&tcl=24&html=1&n=0"; 
script.text=alert('куку'); 
document.body.appebdChild(script);}
```

Но это не работает для меня. Да и не понятно как быть с css партнерки `class="ambn"`

Этот вопрос мне пришлось переписать, так как с мобильного я его опубликовал "непонятно"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить этот код перед body с помощью js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757696/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-body-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js)

Comment: Если вы про нерабочий алерт - когда у скрипта заполнен аттрибут `src` - код внутри тега игнорируется браузером и не выполняется.

Answer (score 2):

```
var script=document.createElement("script"); 
script.type="text/javascript"; 
script.src="//x.mobalert.net/ma.php?s=79849&tr=50&to=1& acl=60&cncl=1&scr=0&tok=1&tcl=24&html=1&n=0"; 
script.className="ambn"; 
document.body.append(script);
```